# Trust to certificates on different ports

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, usability

I have three web applications on the same host.
One of them(main app) listens on port 1234,
Another one(API #1) is on 1235, and the last one(API #2) on 1356.

They're all secured by self-signed SSL/TLS certificates. The same certificate is used for all ports. But (amazingly) web browsers consider all these ports different, and thus requiring me to approve self-signed certificate three times! Obviously, it's very inconvenient.

What's the best way to make trust to this certificate on all ports at once?
(without reconfiguring web browsers).

P.S. I've tested this web app with FF, Opera, Chrome. And all of them have similar behaviour.

Comment: Don't use self signed certificates, but certificates that can be verified by the browsers. Then you don't have to accept anything at all. Such certificates come free of charge these days, read about "Let's encrypt"...

Comment: Why do you need 3 different ports?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I missed notification.
@Christopher Schultz Because I have 2 different APIs written in different languages and served by different application servers.